# CSS selector not working with jquery click function

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to assign a click event to span elements with class 'open' and 'appoint'. But I cannot get it to work. Code is as shown below.

HTML:

```
            <td><span id = "28" class='open'>28</span></td>
            <td><span id = "29" class='open'>29</span></td>
            <td><span id = "30" class='closed'>30</span></td>
            <td><span id = "31" class='appoint'>31</span></td>
            <td><span id = "32" class='closed'>32</span></td>
```

JS:

```
            $("span[class='open'][class='appoint']").click(function() {

                alert($(this).html());

            });
```

I have tried below combinations too, but nothing seems to work.

```
$("span.open.appoint")
$("span .open .appoint")
$("span .open, .appoint")
```

Comment: click function not responding on any of the span elements after applying above class selectors...any ideas???

Comment: Are these HTML-Code generated from Javascript / Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem with the code**

`$("span.open.appoint")`

It selects appoint which has span and open in the same attribute list/node.

`$("span .open .appoint")`

Descendant selector, only when `appoint` is a child of `open`

`$("span .open, .appoint")`

Selects `open` only if it is a child of `span`

**Solution:**

Try with `$("span.open, span.appoint")`

You need to use multiple CSS selectors separated by `,`

```js
$("span.open, span.appoint").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color','lightblue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><span id="28" class='open'>28</span>
</td>
<td><span id="29" class='open'>29</span>
</td>
<td><span id="30" class='closed'>30</span>
</td>
<td><span id="31" class='appoint'>31</span>
</td>
<td><span id="32" class='closed'>32</span>
</td>
```

Comment: I tried it, but click function is not at all working for any of the span elements.

Comment: If you check the output, it is working right? :) Seems like there are other problems to deal with.

Comment: I meant, check the output of my solution. It is working. There must be a problem with your existing code apart from this small portion. Conflicts maybe or the way you have included the script.

Comment: when I use $('span') it works, but after adding class names along with span as selector, click event doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Use **Multiselector** in jquery

```
$("span.open, span.appoint").click(function() {
      alert($(this).html());
 });
```